# Using JOINs and group by together in single sql query

Tags: mysql, select, join, group-by

I'm not able to use JOINS and group-by together:
I searched for this...but I didn't find the solution..Problem is as below:

I have two tables, first is `main_table` with fields `eid`, `name`, `status`

Second table is followups with fields `fid`, `eid`, `last_date`, `remarks`, and `next_date`

Second table is used to store followup details of clients (client details stored in main_table) and i want to get last followup record for each client with selected date period (from_date to to_date) and sort by next_date in descending order.

i used the below query but not working

```
SELECT * 
FROM main_table as MT 
JOIN followups as MF on MT.eid=MF.eid 
WHERE MT.status='open' AND MF.NDate<='2012-12-07' 
GROUP BY MF.eid 
ORDER BY MF.next_date DESC
```

thanks in advance...guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
SELECT * FROM main_table AS MT 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM followups ORDER BY next_date DESC) AS A GROUP BY eid) AS MF ON MT.eid=MF.eid 
WHERE MT.status='open' 
AND MF.NDate<='2012-12-07';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
select m.eid,
  m.name,
  m.status,
  f1.last_date,
  f1.remarks,
  f1.next_date
from maintable m
left join
(
  select max(last_date) maxLast, eid
  from followups
  where last_date between from_date and to_date
  group by eid
) f
  on m.eid = f.eid
left join followups f1
  on f.maxLast = f1.last_date
  and f.eid = f1.eid
where m.status='open'
  and f1.next_date<='2012-12-07'
order by f1.next_date desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM main_table AS MT 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM followups WHERE NDate<='2012-12-07' ORDER BY next_date DESC) AS A GROUP BY eid) AS MF ON MT.eid=MF.eid 
WHERE MT.status='open';
```